# Bootstrap 3: How to precisely center text under a circular image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3, the text is not perfectly aligned under a circular image, this is more obvious on different screens and in bootstrap modals and in different languages, I don't want to start adding `margin-left` because if I do that, I'll be faulty on some screen. Is there a better way?

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Arabic </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Dari </span>
    </div>
    </div> 
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Pashto </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Kurdish </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Farsi </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Tigrinya </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> Amharic </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
    
      <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="country text-center"> English </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr Not sure I understood your question, Each text should be centered below the image above it,. In my example, Arabic and Dari and Farsi are far off the center of the images above them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom class `.center` to your outermost `.container` `div`. This will align the image and text to center using `text-align: center;`.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Arabic </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Dari </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Pashto </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Kurdish </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Farsi </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Tigrinya </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Amharic </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> English </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can also add it to the outermost `row` to get the same effect. I read another comment further down the page. There is also nothing in bootstrap that says you cannot nest containers inside a modal.

Answer (score 2):

The easy fix to your code is just to add `text-center` class to all `col-xs-*` classes. That will center inner images and text inside the `col-xs-*` wrappers. Note I have added some background color to help visualize the effect.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-info">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Arabic </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-warning">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Dari </span>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-info">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Pashto </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-warning">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Kurdish </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-warning">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Farsi </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-info">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Tigrinya </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-warning">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> Amharic </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center bg-info">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="country text-center"> English </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use only one row and then center the image and the text.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row text-center">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" alt="">
            <br>
            <span class="country text-center"> Arabic </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: you can still use the columns... I've added them to the short version of your example

Comment: Without using boostrap columns? Aligning the items would be a challenge on different screens.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox
**CSS**

```
display : flex;
justify-content : center;
align-items : center
```

Comment: To which element?